# How to implement Zipkin in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin, spring-boot-3

I'm using Java 17, Spring Boot 3, Spring Cloud version 2022.0.4 and Zipkin, but when I configure the properties, it's giving this:

application.properties:

```
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
```

```
Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.zipkin.base-url' 
Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.sleuth.sampler.probability'
```

pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Am I importing the correct dependencies?

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758772/how-to-configure-zipkin-baseurl-in-springboot-3 ?

Comment: I read this. But when I add these properties it shows "Cannot resolve configuration property 'management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint'"

Answer (score 1):

I just added these dependencies on  pom.xml and it worked:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://localhost:9411
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
```